# Ошибка при выполнении интеграционного теста - "Cannot invoke ... because ... is null"

Tags: java, spring-boot, test-automation

Всем привет. Прошу помощи, не могу разобраться.
Класс-контроллер с методом:

```
 @GetMapping("/")
 public List<CodeResponse> getAllCode() {
     List<Code> сodes = сodeService.findAll();
     return сodeMapper.toСodeResponseList(сodes);
 }
```

`Postman` и строка в браузере отрабатывают корректно.

Пытаюсь для него написать интеграционный тест:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class СodeControllerIT {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private codeServiceImpl codeService;

    @MockBean
    private codeMapper codeMapper;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private сodeController сodeController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(сodeController).build();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnAllСodes() throws Exception {
        List<Сode> expectedCodes= ...
        List<CodeResponse> expectedCodeResponses = ...

       when(codeService.findAll()).thenReturn(codes);   
       when(codeMapper.toCodeResponseList(expectedCodes)).thenReturn(expectedCodeResponses);
    
       mockMvc.perform(get("/codes/"))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(content().json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(expectedCodeResponses)));
    }
```

Возвращает ошибку

> Cannot invoke "...CodeServiceImpl.findAll()" because
> "this.codeService" is null

Что я упускаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашла благодаря вот этому сообщению - [Ответ в другой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75179409/cannot-invoke-pacienteservice-findbyidjava-lang-integer-because-this-servic/75180850#75180850)

В итоге надо было просто заменить `@InjectMocks` на `@Autowired`. И не путать аннотации для юнит-тестов и интеграционных тестов.